# How can I save each spinner value in sqlite database?

Tags: android-sqlite

This is my save button button code of my database.

```
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       pd.setFname(et1.getText().toString());

       pd.setLname(et2.getText().toString());

       pd.setPhone(et3.getText().toString());

       pd.setRelation(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());

       int spinner_pos=spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
       String[]relation=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.addrelation);

       String mg = he.save(pd);

       m.setText(mg);
   }
});
```

It is only saving the first spinner value in every record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fast way is to use a loop inside setOnclickListner (there can be some better to do this):

```
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

              int nSpinnerItemsCount = spinner1.getCount();

              for(int nCounter = 0; nCounter < nSpinnerItemsCount; nCounter ++)
              {
                 pd.setFname(et1.getText().toString());

                 pd.setLname(et2.getText().toString());

                 pd.setPhone(et3.getText().toString());

                 pd.setRelation(spinner1.getItemAtPosition(nCounter).toString());
                 String mg = he.save(pd);

                 m.setText(mg);

              }


        });
```

**spinner1.getItemAtPosition(nCounter).toString()** is the key. on your code your use 
**int spinner_pos=spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();**

By default it always return the index of the first element inside the spinner (if other element is selected).

So by using spinner1.getCount, a loop and getItemAtPosition you have all elements in the spinner  and do what you want to do.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It worked at first but now it is taking the last value only ,i did this:for (int nCounter = 0; nCounter < nSpinnerItemsCount; nCounter++)
                                           {

                                               pd.setRelation(spinner1.getItemAtPosition(nCounter).toString());
                                               String[] relation = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.addrelation);
                                               
                                           }